# How to scroll to the very top of the page in Cypress

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to fetch an api and mock data with my own data on search. Below is my cypress code.

In my UI, there is a searchbox at the near top of the page below app header bar. The problem is after fetching data and render, cypress auto scroll the page to the bottom a little bit and what happens is that searchbar is covered by app header bar. So, to type into search box is not possible anymore.

```
it.only("should fetch data on Search and display data", () => {
    const searchText = "product1";
    const apiURL = `products?statuses=[]`;
    
    cy.intercept("GET", apiURL, {
      statusCode : 200,
      body : myMockedResponse
    }).as("getProducts");
    // cy.scrollTo("top", { duration: 500, ensureScrollable : false }); // not working
    cy.viewport(1000, 10000); // this is working
    cy.visit(Product_Path); 
    cy.viewport(1280, 1200);

    cy.wait("@getProducts").then(xhr => {
      cy.wait(2000);

      if (xhr.response) {
        const responseData = xhr.response.body.data;
        const searchedData = responseData.filter(d => d.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())); 

        expect(xhr.response.statusCode).to.equal(200);

        // cy.get("[data-test=search-input]").scrollIntoView(); not working
        // cy.scrollTo("top"); not working
        // cy.scrollTo(0, 0); not working
        cy.get("[data-test=search-input]").type(searchText);

       // assertions using searchedData
      }
    });
  });
```

So, I tried setting really long viewport-height to the page to fit all the content (when it is not fit in viewport) like really crazy value - 10000. and it is working. But, I don't want to use that.

So, I found scrollTo and tried it. Not working. What do I need?

The html structure is:

```
<div data-test="search-input" class="search-input"><input name="search" placeholder="Search" type="text" class="search-input mr-5 rounded-3 form-control"></div>
```

Comment: Would it work if you set force:true, inside type() ?

Comment: No. `failed because it requires a valid typeable element.`

Comment: What is the element? Please show the DOM you are trying to test. It sounds like multiple mistakes but there's not enough info to go on.

Comment: Also, as @Aladin already mentioned you command sequence is wrong.

Comment: The issue is at the moment of getting search box with `cy.get("[data-test=search-input]")`, that element was scrolled and placed at the very top of the page, which lets the top fixed navbar cover it. I tried removing that line `cy.get("[data-test=search-input]").scrollIntoView()` and just tested out of cy.scrollTo("top") / or "bottom", it is working. @art, @Ricky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, to disable auto-scroll this cypress behavior: Adding `"scrollBehavior": false` inside cypress.config.js file.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use `.scrollIntoView()` on the search input, which must be a two-step sequence with the `.type()` in a separate chain.

```js
cy.get("[data-test=search-input]").scrollIntoView()  // unsafe to chain further commands
cy.get("[data-test=search-input]").type(searchText)
```

I would also move those commands outside the response callback

Comment: Not working. still same.